ReactNative expo-av Sound not playing
I am developing a reactnative application for eartraining for pianists. But I've come across an error while trying to play sounds in the app.
import React from 'react'

import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { Text } from 'react-native-paper'
import { TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native'

import { useState } from 'react/cjs/react.development'
import { useEffect } from 'react/cjs/react.development'

import { RandomSound } from '../../functions/sound'//function I made to select a random sound
import { LoadPlay_Sound } from '../../functions/sound'//function I made to load sounds 

import { SmallCustomButton } from '../../functions/functions'//Custom button I made

const FourthFifth = () => {

const [answer,setanswer] = useState();
const [oringalanswer,setoriginalanswer] = useState();
const [sound,setsound] = useState([]);
const [currentsound,setcurrentsound] = useState();
const [changesound,setchangesound] = useState();
const [once,setonce] = useState(0);
const [played,setplayed] = useState(0);
const [correct,setcorrect] = useState(0);

//Loading all the intervals needed
useEffect(() => {
    async function load() {
        Promise.all([LoadPlay_Sound("perfectfourth"),LoadPlay_Sound("perfectfifth")])
        .then(([perfectfourth,perfectfifth])=>{
            setsound({perfectfourth:perfectfourth,perfectfifth:perfectfifth})
        })
        .catch(error=>{
            console.log("An error occured while fetching sounds: "+error)
        })
    }
    load();
}, []);

//Selecting a random interval when Sound state is filled or if changesound value is changed
useEffect(()=>{
    async function setdata() {
        RandomSound(sound)
        .then((currentvalue)=>setcurrentsound(currentvalue))
        .catch(error=>console.log("An error occured during Random selection: "+error))
    }
    if(Object.keys(sound).length>0)
    {  
    setdata()
    }
},[sound,changesound])

//Getting the key of that sound to check wheather the answer is correct. 
//Runs when current sound is changed
useEffect(()=>{
    async function Getkey() {
        for (let key in sound) {
            for(let soundobject of sound[key]){
                if (soundobject === currentsound) {
                    setoriginalanswer(key=="perfectfourth"?"Perfect Fourth":"Perfect Fifth")
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(Object.keys(sound).length>0)
    {  
    Getkey()
    }
},[currentsound])

//When I click on the button to play sound and if i click i again it stops playing
//And it also checks wheather I've pushed it by setting the Setplayed variable
async function handleplaysound(){
    if (currentsound){
        console.log(currentsound+" this is the sound")
        LoadPlay_Sound(currentsound,"play")
        .then(()=>{console.log(" Sound played successfully");setplayed(1)})
        .catch(error=>console.log("Error occured while playing sound "+error))
    }
    else{
        console.log("CurrentSound is not available")
    }
}

//when I click on any of the options
function selectedchoice(choice){

    //If answer is correct.
    //Checks if I've already clicked another option and if I've clicked on the hear button
    if(choice===oringalanswer && once==0 && played==1)
    {
        setanswer("Correct. Click to continue")
        setcorrect(1);
        setonce(1)
    }
    //If answer is wrong
    //Checks if I've already clicked another option and if I've clicked on the hear button
    else if(choice!==oringalanswer && once==0 && played==1)
    {
        setanswer("Wrong answer. It was "+ oringalanswer+"\nClick to continue.")
        setcorrect(2);
        setonce(1)
    }
    //If I haven't played the button to hear the sound atleast once
    else if(played==0)
    {
        setplayed(2)
    }
}

//When I click on the text. It resets all the State values and changes the current sound to new sound
function tonext() 
{
    if(correct==1 || correct==2)
    {
        setchangesound(Math.random()*10)
        setanswer("")
        setonce(0)
        setplayed(0)
        setcorrect(0)
    }
}

//Styles for the buttons and view
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container2:{
        flexDirection:"row",
        margin:10,
    },
    circle:{
        marginBottom:100,
        width:220,
        height:220,
        backgroundColor:"#A9E4F4",
        borderRadius:100,
        borderWidth:played==2?3:1,
        borderColor:played==2?"#E67274":"black",        
        justifyContent: 'center',
        shadowOpacity: 0.5,
        shadowRadius: 16,
        elevation: 25,
    },
    textstyle:{
        fontSize:20,
        textAlign:"center",
    }
    })

  return(
    <View style={{backgroundColor:correct==1?"#CCF8D6":correct==2?"#F8CCCD":"#EFF5EE", flexDirection:"column",justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center',height:"100%",}}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleplaysound} style={styles.circle}><Text style={styles.textstyle}>Play Interval</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={styles.container2}> 
            <SmallCustomButton onPress={()=>selectedchoice("Perfect Fourth")} marginright={50} color={"#7DC345"} size={[10,15]} name="Perfect Fourth"/>
            <SmallCustomButton onPress={()=>selectedchoice("Perfect Fifth")} color={"#7DC345"} size={[10,15]} name="Perfect Fifth"/>
        </View>
        <Text onPress={()=>tonext()} style={{fontWeight:"bold", position:"absolute", top:"57.5%", fontSize:15, color:"#E44346", textAlign:"center"}}>{answer}</Text>
    </View>

  )
  
}

export default FourthFifth


async function handleplaysound(){
    if (currentsound){
        console.log(currentsound+" this is the sound")
        LoadPlay_Sound(currentsound,"play")
        .then(()=>{console.log(" Sound played successfully");setplayed(1)})
        .catch(error=>console.log("Error occured while playing sound "+error))
    }
    else{
        console.log("CurrentSound is not available")
    }
}

When I click on the big circle that says "Play interval" the above code will run to play the sound. But it isn't playing. Rarely it does play the sound and most of the time it doesn't. When the sound does play it only works once. when I click on the circle again it doesn't play. Then I will have click on the text to run the below code to reset the sound to a new sound:
function tonext() 
{
    if(correct==1 || correct==2)
    {
        setchangesound(Math.random()*10)
        setanswer("")
        setonce(0)
        setplayed(0)
        setcorrect(0)
    }
}

After reseting it may or may not work. but if it does work then like always it only plays the sound once.
The below code is the sound.js from which I import 'LoadPlay_Sound' and 'RandomSound'.
import {Audio} from 'expo-av'

const LoadPlay_Sound = async (file,play) => {

    async function createaudio(avobject) 
    {
      const soundobject = new Audio.Sound();
  
      try {
        await soundobject.loadAsync(avobject);
        return soundobject;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error occured while creating sound object in Sound.js: "+error)
      }
    }
  
    if(file=="minorsecond")
    {
      try{
      const audios = await Promise.all([
        createaudio(require("../sounds/MinorSecond/MinorSecond-1.wav")),
        createaudio(require("../sounds/MinorSecond/MinorSecond-2.wav")),
        createaudio(require("../sounds/MinorSecond/MinorSecond-3.wav")),
        createaudio(require("../sounds/MinorSecond/MinorSecond-4.wav")),
        createaudio(require("../sounds/MinorSecond/MinorSecond-5.wav"))
      ])
      return audios;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error occured while fetching MinorSecond in Sound.js: "+error)
      }
    }
  
    else if(file=="majorsecond")
    {
      try{
      const audios = await Promise.all([
        createaudio(require("../sounds/MajorSecond/MajorSecond-1.wav")),
        createaudio(require("../sounds/MajorSecond/MajorSecond-2.wav")),
        createaudio(require("../sounds/MajorSecond/MajorSecond-3.wav")),
        createaudio(require("../sounds/MajorSecond/MajorSecond-4.wav")),
        createaudio(require("../sounds/MajorSecond/MajorSecond-5.wav"))
      ])
      return audios;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error occured while fetching MajorSecond in Sound.js: "+error)
      }
    }
  
    else if(file=="minorthird")
    {
      try { 
        const audios = await Promise.all([
          createaudio(require("../sounds/MinorThird/MinorThird-1.wav")),
          createaudio(require("../sounds/MinorThird/MinorThird-2.wav")),
          createaudio(require("../sounds/MinorThird/MinorThird-3.wav")),
          createaudio(require("../sounds/MinorThird/MinorThird-4.wav")),
          createaudio(require("../sounds/MinorThird/MinorThird-5.wav"))
        ])
        return audios
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error occured while fetching MinorThird in Sound.js: "+error)
      }
    }
  
    else if(file=="majorthird")
    {
      try{
      const audios = await Promise.all([
        createaudio(require("../sounds/MajorThird/MajorThird-1.wav")),
        createaudio(require("../sounds/MajorThird/MajorThird-2.wav")),
        createaudio(require("../sounds/MajorThird/MajorThird-3.wav")),
        createaudio(require("../sounds/MajorThird/MajorThird-4.wav")),
        createaudio(require("../sounds/MajorThird/MajorThird-5.wav"))
      ])
      return audios;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error occured while fetching MajorThird in Sound.js: "+error)
      }
    }
  
    else if(file=="perfectfourth")
    {
      try{
      const audios = await Promise.all([
        createaudio(require("../sounds/PerfectFourth/PerfectFourth-1.wav")),
        createaudio(require("../sounds/PerfectFourth/PerfectFourth-2.wav")),
        createaudio(require("../sounds/PerfectFourth/PerfectFourth-3.wav")),
        createaudio(require("../sounds/PerfectFourth/PerfectFourth-4.wav")),
        createaudio(require("../sounds/PerfectFourth/PerfectFourth-5.wav"))
      ])
      return audios;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error occured while fetching PerfectFourth in Sound.js: "+error)
      }
    }
  
    else if(file=="perfectfifth")
    {
      try{
      const audios = await Promise.all([
        createaudio(require("../sounds/PerfectFifth/PerfectFifth-1.wav")),
        createaudio(require("../sounds/PerfectFifth/PerfectFifth-2.wav")),
        createaudio(require("../sounds/PerfectFifth/PerfectFifth-3.wav")),
        createaudio(require("../sounds/PerfectFifth/PerfectFifth-4.wav")),
        createaudio(require("../sounds/PerfectFifth/PerfectFifth-5.wav"))
      ])
      return audios;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error occured while fetching PerfectFifth in Sound.js: "+error)
      }
    }
  
    else if(file=="minorsixth")
    {
      try{
      const audios = await Promise.all([
        createaudio(require("../sounds/MinorSixth/MinorSixth-1.wav")),
        createaudio(require("../sounds/MinorSixth/MinorSixth-2.wav")),
        createaudio(require("../sounds/MinorSixth/MinorSixth-3.wav")),
        createaudio(require("../sounds/MinorSixth/MinorSixth-4.wav")),
        createaudio(require("../sounds/MinorSixth/MinorSixth-5.wav"))
      ])
      return audios;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error occured while fetching MinorSixth in Sound.js: "+error)
      }
    }
  
    else if(file=="majorsixth")
    {
      try{
      const audios = await Promise.all([
        createaudio(require("../sounds/MajorSixth/MajorSixth-1.wav")),
        createaudio(require("../sounds/MajorSixth/MajorSixth-2.wav")),
        createaudio(require("../sounds/MajorSixth/MajorSixth-3.wav")),
        createaudio(require("../sounds/MajorSixth/MajorSixth-4.wav")),
        createaudio(require("../sounds/MajorSixth/MajorSixth-5.wav"))
      ])
      return audios;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error occured while fetching MajorSixth in Sound.js: "+error)
      }
    }
  
    else if(file=="minorseventh")
    {
      try{
      const audios = await Promise.all([
        createaudio(require("../sounds/MinorSeventh/MinorSeventh-1.wav")),
        createaudio(require("../sounds/MinorSeventh/MinorSeventh-2.wav")),
        createaudio(require("../sounds/MinorSeventh/MinorSeventh-3.wav")),
        createaudio(require("../sounds/MinorSeventh/MinorSeventh-4.wav")),
        createaudio(require("../sounds/MinorSeventh/MinorSeventh-5.wav"))
      ])
      return audios;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error occured while fetching MinorSeventh in Sound.js: "+error)
      }
    }
  
    else if(file=="majorseventh")
    {
      try{
      const audios = await Promise.all([
        createaudio(require("../sounds/MajorSeventh/MajorSeventh-1.wav")),
        createaudio(require("../sounds/MajorSeventh/MajorSeventh-2.wav")),
        createaudio(require("../sounds/MajorSeventh/MajorSeventh-3.wav")),
        createaudio(require("../sounds/MajorSeventh/MajorSeventh-4.wav")),
        createaudio(require("../sounds/MajorSeventh/MajorSeventh-5.wav"))
      ])
      return audios;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error occured while fetching MajorSeventh in Sound.js: "+error)
      }
    }
  
    else if(file=="octave")
    {
      try{
      const audios = await Promise.all([
        createaudio(require("../sounds/Octave/Octave-1.wav")),
        createaudio(require("../sounds/Octave/Octave-2.wav")),
        createaudio(require("../sounds/Octave/Octave-3.wav")),
        createaudio(require("../sounds/Octave/Octave-4.wav")),
        createaudio(require("../sounds/Octave/Octave-5.wav"))
      ])
      return audios;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error occured while fetching Octave in Sound.js: "+error)
      }
    }
    else if(play=="play")
    {
      try{
        await file.playAsync();
      }
      catch(error){
        console.log("Error occured while playing the sound in Sound.js: "+error)
      }

    }
    else if(play=="stop")
    {
      try{
        await file.stopAsync(); 
      }
      catch(error){
        console.log("Error occured while stoping the sound in Sound.js: "+error)
      }
    }
  
  } 

  
const RandomSound = async (soundobject) => {
  try {
    const dictkey = Object.keys(soundobject)
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random()*dictkey.length)
    let value = dictkey[index]
    value = soundobject[value]
    const index2 =  Math.floor(Math.random(value)*value.length)
    return value[index2];
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error while selecting a random sound object in Sound.js: "+error)
  }
} 

export {RandomSound, LoadPlay_Sound}

The above code is for importing sound files, playing sound, stoping sound and for selecting a random sound object
In the below code I've tried to log the problem:
//In the interface file
    async function handleplaysound(){
        if (currentsound){
            console.log(currentsound+" this is the sound")
            LoadPlay_Sound(currentsound,"play")
            .then(()=>{console.log(" Sound played successfully");setplayed(1)})
            .catch(error=>console.log("Error occured while playing sound "+error))
        }
        else{
            console.log("CurrentSound is not available")
        }
    }
    
//In the sound.js file
     else if(play=="play")
     {
         try{
           await file.playAsync();
       }
         catch(error){
           console.log("Error occured while playing the sound in Sound.js: "+error)
       }
    
     }

There weren't any problems when loading the sound files but when I click on the "Play Interval" button it sometimes throws me error saying:

LOG  [object Object] this is the sound  LOG  Error occured while playing the sound in Sound.js: Error: Player does not exist.
LOG  Sound played successfully

And most of the time it doesn't throw any error but sound just doesn't play. like I said it only plays the first time and then doesn't. The LOG then would look like this:

LOG  [object Object] this is the sound
LOG  Sound played successfully

Also when I opened my project in the browser it works fine. The problem mentioned is only caused when I open it on my phone using expo QR code. I've provided video explanation of the problem in detail below.
This is how it works in the browser: https://youtube.com/shorts/ZHsYHXcJXYA?feature=share
This is how it works in the Mobile: https://youtube.com/shorts/9zUjd2mzTD0?feature=share
Thank you.

I am having the same error after I used my app for a while "Error: Player does not exist."
Thank you for creating the reproducible error @Fame Star.
Did you cut a ticket to expo? I think you should https://github.com/expo/expo/issues
